# Warning: Parameter id_lang in function displayDate() is deprecated

Tags: php, deprecated, prestashop-1.5

I got this error in `prestashop 1.5`

> Warning: Parameter id_lang in function displayDate() is deprecated in /Applications/MAMP/htdocs/sviluppo/classes/helper/HelperList.php on line 287
>   in /Applications/MAMP/htdocs/sviluppo/classes/Tools.php on line 2147

This is the line 287 of HelperList.php

```
$this->_list[$index][$key] = Tools::displayDate($tr[$key], $this->context->language->id, true);
```

Answer (score 0):

fixed:

```
$this->_list[$index][$key] = Tools::displayDate($tr[$key],null , true);
```

Comment: What does that do? How does it answer the question? Don't just blurt out code! https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer

Comment: Code only answers are discouraged. Please add some explanation as to how this solves the problem. [From Review](https://stackoverflow.com/review/low-quality-posts/23986140)

Comment: Here is the official prestashop fix https://github.com/PrestaShop/PrestaShop-1.5/commit/3328c7a653dfce5a494b014bde6410261104def8#diff-66f353a25bcde6c1c85685b749bb0882